# How to echo single value in multiarray

Tags: php

How to echo subaru in below example:

Copy/paste php here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_array_multi

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$cars = array 
(
  array
    (
        "Volvo",222,18,
        array("Subaru",112,12)
    ),
  array("BMW",15,13),

);

echo $cars[0][0].": In stock: ".$cars[0][1].", sold: ".$cars[0][2].".<br>";
echo $cars[1][0].": In stock: ".$cars[1][1].", sold: ".$cars[1][2].".<br>";
echo $cars[0][0][0]." how to access subaru?!".".<br>";

print "<pre>";
print_r($cars);
print "</pre>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: echo $cars[0][3][0]

Comment: simply try `$cars[0][3][0]`, See: https://3v4l.org/bh69M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To echo the word **subaru** you can use the following

```
<?php
$cars = array 
(
  array
    (
        "Volvo",222,18,
        array("Subaru",112,12)
    ),
  array("BMW",15,13),

);
echo $cars[0][3][0];
?>
```